# How to add an event to a different user's calendar

Tags: google-calendar, permissions

Is there a way to upload the iCalendar (calendar file) to a different person's Google Calendar directly?

I shouldn't be able to view the other person's calendar but I should be able to upload calendar events directly (Note: I do have the permission to upload to his calendar).

How should I achieve this?

Does the other person need to provide me any rights/permissions in Google Calendar to authorize such activity?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:  This uses Jquery and a small plugin to generate add to Calendar and If you wish even using ical/vcal to users desktop calendars
Works like a charm
https://github.com/tardate/jquery.addtocalendar